# MVC4 Controller Type and Action MethodInfo from AuthorizeAttribute AuthorizeCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I am trying to create an authorization system that allows me to use various data from a Controllers Type and an Actions MethodInfo to check if a user has rights to access that section of my system.

```
public class NewAuth : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var Type = ControllerTypeHere;
        var MethodInfo = ActionMethodInfoHere;
    }
}
```

Is there any way of getting the Type and Method info of the action or controller that is currently trying to be accessed?

I can supply any other info if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OnAuthorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is a good way to get some information about the request.

Let's make a few modifications to your code.

```
public class NewAuth : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private Type _type;
    private ActionDescriptor _actionDescriptor;

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        _type = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
        _actionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // use _type
        // use _actionDescriptor
        return true;
    }
}
```

`OnAuthorization` is fired first, so the variables will be set when `AuthorizationCore` is called. You'll notice that I've changed the concept of [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) to [ActionDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actiondescriptor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). They aren't interchangable, but ActionDescriptor is a helpful way to get some common information about the action such as `ActionName`, `FilterAttributes`, `CustomAttributes` and `Parameters`.

If MethodInfo is required, it's certainly doable but it can be a little trickier. Remember that your controller might have several actions that have the same name; an HttpGet version, HttpPost version etc.

In this example I'm looking for the [HttpPost] version of the action:

```
var methodInfo = _type.GetMethods()
    .SingleOrDefault(mi => mi.Name == filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName &&
        mi.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(attr => attr is HttpGetAttribute));
```

Comment: Now I don't know if my situation is caused by something else, but if anyone has a problem with this solution - try assigning the private fields before calling `base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);`, I experienced that otherwise `AuthorizeCore` will throw a NullException, because they have not been set in time. Anyways, +1 for this solution!

Comment: Yes, this is actually backwards; base.OnAuthorization calls AuthorizeCore, so in OnAuthorization you must do your setup first before calling the base version